# how do I make an onClickListener pull up an url or perform an google search using if else statments in a webview for a android browser

Tags: java, android, if-statement, url, webview

I'm new to programming as of a year now and I'm working on an Browser app for android. My goal is to have a user, enter an URL in a TextEdit field and it goes to a website or they just type in a word and it performs a google search.

I know I must us an if else statment to do this. my problem is how exactly to go about doing so. originally ive tried

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private Object URL;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

            if (webView == (WebView) URL); {
                webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf(editText.getText()));
                editText.setText("");
            }

            if (webView == editText.setText(""); {
                webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/#q=" + editText.getText());
            }





        }
    });
```

im getting an ')' expected error thats all thats showing but im sure theres more to this it does not feel right, hopefully you all can help me.

Comment: You have a semicolon (;) after each **IF** statement condition where there **shouldn't be one** and you are missing the closing parentheses here: `if (webView == editText.setText(""); {`. It should be: `if (webView == editText.setText("")) {`.

Comment: but when i do that i run into an.. operator '==' cannot be applied to android.webkit.webview,'void' i have a feeling im not even close to setting this up right

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this was for android otherwise I would have ignored the question.

Comment: why do you say that?